# Flutter : EdgeInsetsGeometry? can't be assigned to EdgeInsetsGeometry

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to make helper constants in my project so that I don't have to type the syntax again and again. This is the code.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

// Images

Map<String, String> images = {
  'APP_LOGO': 'lib/resources/globals/assets/images/app_logo.png'
};

// Colors

Map<String, Color> colors = {
  'PRIMARY_FONT_COLOR': const Color(0xFF000000),
  'SECONDARY_FONT_COLOR': const Color(0xFF4FAFF5),
};

// Paddings

Map<String, EdgeInsetsGeometry> paddings = {
  // ALL
  'P_1': const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
  'P_2': const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
  'P_3': const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
  'P_4': const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),

  // HORIZONTAL
  'PX_1': const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 0, horizontal: 5.0),
  'PX_2': const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 0, horizontal: 10.0),
  'PX_3': const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 0, horizontal: 15.0),
  'PX_4': const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 0, horizontal: 20.0),

  // VERTICAL
  'PY_1': const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5.0, horizontal: 0),
  'PY_2': const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 0),
  'PY_3': const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15.0, horizontal: 0),
  'PY_4': const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20.0, horizontal: 0),
};

// Text Alignment

Map<String, TextAlign> text_alignment = {
  'CENTER': TextAlign.center,
  'LEFT': TextAlign.left,
  'RIGHT': TextAlign.right,
  'JUSTIFY': TextAlign.justify,
};
```

Now when I try to use these constants inside a widget like following,

```
Image.asset(global_constants.images['APP_LOGO'].toString()),
Text(
    local_strings.headings['ABOUT_BENJI'].toString(),
    style: local_constants.text_styles['ABOUT_BENJI'],
    textAlign: global_constants.text_alignment['CENTER'],
 ),
```

It works as expected but I don't know what happens in case of the `Padding` Widget.
Use the constant for padding,  `padding: global_constants.paddings['PX_5']`.

The error I get `Error: The argument type 'EdgeInsetsGeometry?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'EdgeInsetsGeometry'     because 'EdgeInsetsGeometry?' is nullable and 'EdgeInsetsGeometry' isn't.`

Now I do understand the error but, how do I overcome this. I mean all the other constants are working except the padding widget. Any suggestions are welcome. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens because the `[]` operator [returns a nullable type](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.13.4/dart-core/Map/operator_get.html) of your map values. This is by design so it can return null if the given key is not in the map.

To fix this, you need to add a [`!` null assertion operator](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety#null-assertion-operator) and cast to a non nullable type, if you are sure that the variable is non null. So in your case,

```
padding: global_constants.paddings['PX_5']!
```

However, to be honest I recommend against your current design pattern - you are much better off using constants instead of maps, so

```dart
abstract class Paddings {
  static const P_1 = const EdgeInsets.all(5.0);
  static const P_2 = const EdgeInsets.all(10.0);
  static const P_3 = const EdgeInsets.all(15.0);
  static const P_4 = const EdgeInsets.all(20.0);
}
```

and so on. That way, you sidestep the nullability problem altogether.